# How to execute code from one thread in another particular thread?

Tags: java, android

Given the following code snippet:

```
    private void foo(Callback callback) {
        // Unknown Thread

        future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            if (object.getData() == OtherObject.DATA_EXPECTED) {

                callback.onComplete(object.getImportantData()); //want run this in the Unknown Thread
                future.cancel(true);
            }
        },0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

I want to execute the line of code `callback.onComplete(object.getImportantData());` on another thread. Otherwise the following piece of code may fail.

I know how to execute code in the main thread through `Activity.runOnUiThread()` and other useful methods but I don't want this, I want to execute the code in the unknown thread which is given by the class that calls the foo method. This thread can be the main thread or not.

I want to know if there is any way to do what I want to achieve or if what I want to achieve is wrong and I should do something else to solve my particular situation. Any suggestions would be welcome and thank you.

Comment: You can not execute code on an arbitrary thread that is not designed to do so (e.g. a scheduler thread that get it's jobs from a job queue).